# Javascript в XSLT

Tags: javascript, xslt

Нужно в результирующем документе ставить текущую дату и надо вставить код джаваскрипт в шаблон, который будет дату выводить, ведь это нельзя сделать средствами xslt. Как вставить джаваскрипт функцию выводящую текущую дату в тело xslt-шаблона?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:abcd="http://www.tdwg.org/schemas/abcd/2.06"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="abcd:DataSets">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="letter"
                               page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in"
                               margin-top="0.5in" margin-bottom="0.5in"
                               margin-left="0.5in" margin-right="0.5in">
          <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>

      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="letter">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:for-each select="abcd:DataSet">
            <!-- тут нужно вывести дату текущую -->
            
            ...

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: [Can an XSLT insert the current date?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1575134/2881286)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если вы используете .Net `XslCompiledTransform`, вот как это реализовать на c#.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:csharp="urn:my-scripts" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl csharp">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <CurrentDateTime>
                <xsl:value-of select="csharp:CurrentDateTime('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff')"/>
            </CurrentDateTime>
            <CurrentDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="csharp:CurrentDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd')"/>
            </CurrentDate>
            <DefaultDateTime>
                <xsl:value-of select="csharp:CurrentDateTime('')"/>
            </DefaultDateTime>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="csharp">
    <![CDATA[
       public string CurrentDateTime(string format)
       {
            // default format
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format)) {
                format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz";
            }

            return DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
       }
    ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Результат**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <CurrentDateTime>2023-07-01T22:47:26.224</CurrentDateTime>
  <CurrentDate>2023-07-01</CurrentDate>
  <DefaultDateTime>2023-07-01T22:47:26.224-04:00</DefaultDateTime>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

У меня нет вашей среды, поэтому я сделал это для Microsoft Windows. Возможно, вам потребуется настроить функцию и ее интеграцию в XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:jscript="http://www.url.com"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl jscript">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <CurrentDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="jscript:CurrentDate()"/>
            </CurrentDate>
            <CurrentDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="jscript:CurrentDateFormatted()"/>
            </CurrentDate>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="jscript"><![CDATA[
    function CurrentDate(){
        var today = new Date();
    
        return today.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU');
    }

    function CurrentDateFormatted(){
        var today = new Date();
        var Year = today.getFullYear();
        var Month = ((today.getMonth()+1).length != 2 ? "0" + (today.getMonth() + 1) : (today.getMonth()+1));
        var Day = (today.getDate().length != 2 ?"0" + today.getDate() : today.getDate());
    
        return Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day;
    }
    ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Результат**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <CurrentDate>Wednesday, July 5, 2023</CurrentDate>
  <CurrentDate>2023-07-05</CurrentDate>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0 with EXSLT**

Похоже, что libxslt не поддерживает функции расширения, написанные на Javascript.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                extension-element-prefixes="date str func"
                xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                exclude-result-prefixes="str func">
    <xsl:import href="date.format-date.function.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <CurrentDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="date:date-time()"/>
            </CurrentDate>
            <CurrentDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="date:format-date(date:date-time(),'yyyy-MMM-dd')"/>
            </CurrentDate>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Результат**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <CurrentDate>2023-07-05T15:37:40-04:00</CurrentDate>
  <CurrentDate>2023-Jul-05</CurrentDate>
</root>
```

Comment: нет, у меня питон на линуксе

Comment: Анонимный даунвотер, пожалуйста, объясните, почему вы проголосовали против.

Comment: Я не голосовала вообще, просто у меня это не работает

Comment: У вас была возможность попробовать решение, предложенное @Grundy?

Comment: Да, я попробовала вариант для 2.0, но видимо, не поддерживается у меня эта версия xslt, а с решением для 1.0 у меня ничего не вышло

Comment: Какой у вас процессор XSLT и его соответствие стандартам XSLT: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 или 4.0?

Comment: Я обновил ответ с вариантом для Microsoft JаvаScript.

Comment: Это про процессор:

`Using libxml 20912, libxslt 10134 and libexslt 820
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20910, libxslt 10134 and libexslt 820
libxslt 10134 was compiled against libxml 20910
libexslt 820 was compiled against libxml 20910`

Спасибо, но у меня не сработает конструкция `msxsl:script`

Comment: Похоже, что libxslt не поддерживает функции расширения, написанные на Javascript: https://github.com/albanm/node-libxslt/issues/2.

Comment: Да, очень может быть такое(

Comment: Вам нужно вернуться к решению предложенному @Grundy.

Comment: Да, но я не могу разобраться как её установить. Я так понимаю, там нужно тянуть весь архив и куда-то его заливать

Comment: Я обновил ответ третьим XSLT с помощью EXSLT. Какой у ваc адрес электронной почты? Я пришлю вам вам все файлы.

Comment: *"Libxslt is based on libxml2 the XML C library developed for the GNOME project. It also implements most of the EXSLT set of processor-portable extensions functions and some of Saxon's evaluate and expressions extensions."* Вы можете попробовать `date-time()` даже без EXSLT.

Comment: `File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 316, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored
XSLTParseError: Cannot resolve URI /root/.bauble/date.format-date.function.xsl`

Comment: stackoverflow не разрешает вложения. Вот почему я предложил отправить вам по электронной почте все необходимые файлы.

Comment: Извините, но я не хотела бы публиковать свой емейл здесь. Может быть можно как то по другому списаться?

Comment: Вы можете найти меня в LinkedIn

Comment: Вы приняли мои решения как ответ. Что сработало для вас в концов?